# `xr` Cross-Reference: Change Colour for External References Only

Tags: hyperref, color, hyperlink, xr

I want to reference between two files, say Paper1 and Paper2. I'm using `hyperref` in each of the documents for internal references. So as to make clear which references are internal and which are external, I'd like to change the colour of the `xr` references.

In `hypersetup`, I've chosen `linkcolor={blue}`. In essence, I'd like to be able to say

```
if reference is external, then set linkcolor={red}
if reference is internal, then set linkcolor={blue}
```

---

I have set up an example in Overleaf, which can be found here: https://www.overleaf.com/4688282852jxtxcsdmnrhs.
A copy of the files are given below (apologies that they are so long!)

(There is additional 'helper code' in Overleaf that, I believe, is not required if one is compiling locally; see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf.)

```
%%File1.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue},
    citecolor={blue},
    urlcolor={blue}
}

%%% HELPER CODE FOR DEALING WITH EXTERNAL REFERENCES
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{
  \typeout{(#1)}
  \@addtofilelist{#1}
  \IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{
    \externaldocument{#1}
    \addFileDependency{#1.tex}
    \addFileDependency{#1.aux}
}
%%% END HELPER CODE

% put all the external documents here!
\myexternaldocument{File2}

\title{\texttt{xr} package example}
\author{Overleaf team}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
We would like to reference section \ref{label1} of file2.tex
\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%File2.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Label1}
\label{label1}
This section is referenced by File1.
\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%latexmkrc

add_cus_dep( 'tex', 'aux', 0, 'makeexternaldocument' );

sub makeexternaldocument {
    # if the dependency isn't one of the files that this latexmk run will consider, process it
    # without this test, we would get an infinite loop!
    if (!($root_filename eq $_[0]))
    {   # PLEASE ENABLE ONLY ONE OF THE FOLLOWING
        # DEPENDING ON THE ENGINE YOU'RE USING

        # FOR PDFLATEX
        system( "latexmk -pdf \"$_[0]\"" );

        # FOR LATEX+DVIPDF
        # system( "latexmk \"$_[0]\"" );

        # FOR XELATEX
        # system( "latexmk -xelatex \"$_[0]\"" );

        # FOR LUALATEX
        # system( "latexmk -lualatex \"$_[0]\"" );
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't link to an external site. Such links will be dead at some time and then the question is not longer useful. (and without overleaf account one can't follow your link anyway). Copy the example here.

Comment: Have done! :) -- although if someone is to do it locally, various of the parts aren't needed: one can remove everything in the `helper code` (other than `\usepackage{xr-hyper}`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should load xr-hyper before hyperref. Beside this: with xr-hyper the colors are different by default, you are only not seeing it as you changed the `linkcolor` to blue and so to a color quite similar to `filecolor`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue},
    filecolor={red}, %<----
    urlcolor={blue},
    citecolor={blue}
}


\externaldocument[ex:]{external}

\begin{document}

\section{My section}\label{sec:mysection}

Local ref: \ref{sec:mysection}, external ref:  \ref{ex:sec:mytitle} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
%external.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{MyTitle}\label{sec:mytitle}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you confirm definitively that `xr-hyper` should be before `hyperref`? Only *Overleaf* says this: "If you're using the hyperref package in your main file (i.e. File1.tex), then load xr-hyper instead of xr in File1.tex after hyperref."

Comment: load it later and look in the log: `Package xr-hyper Warning: Load package `hyperref' after `xr-hyper'.`

Comment: Fair enough! Perhaps you can add that you must load the external documents after hyperref too (at least, it didn't work for me before, and works after)

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, but unfortunately `xr-hyper` is so buggy that, of the four documents I wanted to cross-reference, it just wouldn't work with the body of one of them -- some parts of the body it wouldn't accept, but didn't give a reason. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: if you find a bug in xr-hyper report it (with a small complete example) here: https://github.com/ho-tex/hyperref. We can then look at it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find exactly where the bug was. I could cross-reference two of the three documents, but the third had something in the body that it didn't like. It is a fairly long document, and I decided it wasn't worth the effort. I don't mind uploading the full documents, though, but it certainly wouldn't be a "small" complete example! (indeed, I couldn't make one of these)

Comment: it is naturally easier to claim without any proof that xr-hyper is buggy then to find the errors in your documents. And no, uploading a large document is not ok. If you think it is not worth it to identify the problem, why should we bother?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you should bother helping me -- indeed, I didn't request that, nor ask for it. I merely thought that you may be one of the administrators of the package, and wanted to make changes. All I wanted was to change the colour of something; it's not worth hours and hours of anyone's time!!

Comment: It's pretty clear that there's a bug though: I have identical preamble in all my files, and I'm having issues with one particular file; if I comment out some parts of the body then I can cross-reference it with the other files, but I didn't work out which part

Comment: Yes I'm one of the maintainer, that's why it is bothering me if you claim it has a bug as I normally want to correct bugs. But I can only resolve it if you take part in the process and spent some of *your* time to build a usable test document.